# kitchen sink converting an undermount sink to a drop in sink on tile counter

Tags: plumbing-fixture

we have a house built in early 1970.  The kitchen sink rusted through so it must be replaced.  We have a ceramic tiled counter top with an undermount sink. We are having great difficulty finding a stanless steel sink to replace it  but we have been able to find overmount sinks.  How do we go about converting the undermont withe drop in? The old sink was cemented in then grouted and tiled.Help!!!